# How to validate is LCID proper?

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, lcid

I need to check that I get the `int` value which is the valid LCID of CultureInfo. Unfortunately, `CultureInfo` doesn't contain something like `bool TryGetCultureInfo(int, out CultureInfo)` method. Also I see that some `CultureInfo` items have the same `LCID`.

So I can use this way:

```
var lcids = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes
    .AllCultures).Select(c => c.LCID).OrderBy(
    c => c).ToArray(); // it contains duplicates

HashSet<int> repeated = new HashSet<int>();

for (int i = 1; i < lcids.Length; i++) {
    if (lcids[i] == lcids[i - 1]) {
        repeated.Add(lcids[i]);
    }
}

foreach (var item in repeated) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

> 4
>   4096
>   31748

I can check wether `repeated` variable contains the checked value, but it seems bad for me... Also I can try to use constructor inside of `try\catch` block but it is bad method because it will be used in iteration and can decrease the speed.

How can I check LCID validation without `try\catch` block and without my code which I show before?

Comment: LCID was deprecated 10 years ago, it could no longer scale to handle the ever increasing number of cultures supported by Windows.  Replaced by culture names that were already common in .NET, like "en-US".  It is completely unclear why you want to use it, just don't.

Comment: AutoCAD application uses LCID in the registry subkey names. For example: ACAD-E001:409. At this case 409 is LCID. I parse such strings.

Comment: @AndreyBushman : Did you get any answer for this? (I also need solution for this situation)